# Finding an attribute in XML based on name

Tags: xml, openweathermap

I'm pretty new to using XML documents. Previously, I had pulled the value I needed based on position ("wCData" is the variable for the loaded XML document):

```cpp
sstring nowImageCode = wCData.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(8).Attributes.Item(2).Value;
```

However, I think the position may have changed, so I need a way to assign the value to a string based on the name instead of position. Here is a sample with the city removed for a token amount of security:

```
<current>
<city id="6666666" name="Timbuktu">
<coord lon="-79.34" lat="37.31"/>
<country>US</country>
<timezone>-18000</timezone>
<sun rise="2019-12-23T12:28:39" set="2019-12-23T22:03:57"/>
</city>
<temperature value="43.43" min="37.99" max="46.99" unit="fahrenheit"/>
<feels_like value="37.06" unit="fahrenheit"/>
<humidity value="61" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="1022" unit="hPa"/>
<wind>
<speed value="4.7" unit="mph" name="Light breeze"/>
<gusts/>
<direction value="40" code="NE" name="NorthEast"/>
</wind>
<clouds value="1" name="clear sky"/>
<visibility value="16093"/>
<precipitation mode="no"/>
<weather number="800" value="clear sky" icon="01d"/>
<lastupdate value="2019-12-23T15:01:55"/>
</current>
```

The value I need to pull is the icon which in this case is "01d".

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string icon = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "weather").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("icon");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The xml is coming from a URL. This is how I'm bringing it in and storing it.                 
` WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wString = wc.DownloadString(currWeatherURL);
   wCData.LoadXml(wString);` I tried implementing your code, putting "wCData" instead of "doc" and "Descendants" had no definition. I have all the "using" statements you have as well.

Comment: There must be a namespace.  I modified code to handle the namespace.